# CS1061 'object' does not contain definition for 'rawtext'

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I've been trying to create a banned word list for a bot I'm creating for a discord, i've been running into trouble of it not recognizing 'rawtext', ive tried researching this issue with no real results.

Here is my code with the error.
any help will be much appreciated.

> CS1061 'object' does not contain definition for 'rawtext'

```
private async Task BadWordsWarn(SocketMessage message, SocketGuildUser user, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string badWord in File.ReadLines(@"bannedwords.txt"))
    {
        if (e.Message.Rawtext.Contains(badWord))
        {
            await ReplyAsync($"{user.Mention} Dont mention that in here");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Discord API, but what type of object is `e.Message`?  You may have to cast it to a specific class to have access to the `Rawtext` property.  Another suggestion is that maybe the property is called `RawText`?  Since that is proper camel-case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where you are getting the `MessageEventArgs` from.
However, I think what you are looking for can be found in the `SocketMessage` instead.

```
var socketUserMessage = message as SocketUserMessage;
if(socketUserMessage == null) return; // do some error handling

foreach (string badWord in File.ReadLines(@"bannedwords.txt"))
{
    if (e.Content.Contains(badWord))
    {
        await ReplyAsync($"{user.Mention} Dont mention that in here");
    }
}
```